# How should I interpret/follow-up on mixed logistic regression (GLMM) diagnostics?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, outliers, glmm, diagnostic

I have experimental data (n subjects = 64) in which the response variable, accuracy (0 or 1), was measured 9 times within subjects. My predictor is Condition (A vs B) measured between subjects. I think the most appropriate model is a logistic one with random intercepts for subjects:

```
model<-glmer(Acc ~ Condition + (1|ID), data= trialDF, family = binomial(logit))
```

I ran diagnostics to test for influential points (Cook's Distance and DFBetas) but I am not sure what the most appropriate cutoffs are and what should be done if there are points that exceed these cutoffs.

Specifically, for Cook's D I'd previously heard that only Ds greater than 1 are problematic, but others suggest D's greater than 3 times the SD. I had 4 datapoints that exceeded the latter criterion, and so reran the model without them and the coefficients didn't change, but when I reran the diagnostics there were new influential points...

I've also read that Cook's D isn't really relevant if you are interested primarily in the influence of points on your coefficients. That is what I'm mostly concerned about. So I calculated the dfbetas as follows:

```
influence <- influence(modela, "ID"); dfbetas(influence)
```

but I don't know what magnitude of dfbeta is cause for concern, and how to address it.

Also, I have no reason to think that any outliers should be discarded from the model. All points are valid. So I'm not sure what course of action is most appropriate.